# (SIGABRT) code -6 Check failed: instrumentation frame method

Tags: android

It is random and goes away when I rebuild app and redeploy. I am updating views by fetching information from database.

**This is stack**

```
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
A/art: art/runtime/stack.cc:848] Check failed: instrumentation_frame.method_ == GetMethod() (instrumentation_frame.method_=0x70f7b720, GetMethod()=0x70af8d68) Expected: void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) Found: <runtime method>.<runtime internal callee-save reference and argument registers method><no signature>
A/art: art/runtime/stack.cc:848] Check failed: instrumentation_frame.method_ == GetMethod() (instrumentation_frame.method_=0x70f7b720, GetMethod()=0x70af8d68) Expected: void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) Found: <runtime method>.<runtime internal callee-save reference and argument registers method><no signature>
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:403] 
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 32299 (xxx.xxx)
        [ 12-29 15:20:42.680   270:  270 W/         ]
        debuggerd: handling request: pid=32299 uid=10102 gid=10102 tid=32299
```

Comment: I get this only in debug mode and we are not using Instant Run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to turn off Instant Run. It's helped for me.

Comment: Works for me too, but I hope to find the real solution to start using Instant Run again.